# SQL ERROR: Unable to match boolean column in table with column name obtained from another table

Tags: mysql, sql, amazon-redshift

I have a query which returns the name of a boolean column in another table.
I need to return all results which have the same column name = true.

> Getting ERROR:  argument of WHERE must be type boolean, not type
>   character varying

I understand the issue, how to modify the query for the server to identify the variable as a column name?

Query:

```
WITH c2 AS(
WITH static_vertical_distribution AS (
 SELECT clean_url, UID, VBUSINESS, VENTERTAINMENT, VFASHION, VFOOD, VHOME, VLUXURY, VNEWS, VSPORTS, VTRAVEL FROM table2017_09_11 WHERE uid='XXXXX' UNION ALL 
 SELECT clean_url, UID, VBUSINESS, VENTERTAINMENT, VFASHION, VFOOD, VHOME, VLUXURY, VNEWS, VSPORTS, VTRAVEL FROM table2017_09_10 WHERE uid='XXXX' 
UNION ALL 

 SELECT clean_url, UID, VBUSINESS, VENTERTAINMENT, VFASHION, VFOOD, VHOME, VLUXURY, VNEWS, VSPORTS, VTRAVEL FROM table_2017_09_09 WHERE uid='XXXX'),

cte AS(
 select 'BUSINESS & TECHNOLOGY' as vertical, 'vbusiness' as col, count(distinct clean_url) as vertical_count from static_vertical_distribution where vbusiness union all
 select 'ENTERTAINMENT' as vertical, 'ventertainment' as col, count(distinct clean_url) as vertical_count from static_vertical_distribution where ventertainment union all
 select 'FASHION & BEAUTY' as vertical, 'vfashion' as col, count(distinct clean_url) as vertical_count from static_vertical_distribution where vfashion union all
 select 'FOOD & ENTERTAINING' as vertical, 'vfood' as col, count(distinct clean_url) as vertical_count from static_vertical_distribution where vfood union all
 select 'HOME & DESIGN' as vertical, 'vhome' as col, count(distinct clean_url) as vertical_count from static_vertical_distribution where vhome union all
 select 'LUXURY & DESIGN' as vertical, 'vluxury' as col, count(distinct clean_url) as vertical_count from static_vertical_distribution where vluxury union all
 select 'NEWS' as vertical, 'vnews' as col, count(distinct clean_url) as vertical_count from static_vertical_distribution where vnews union all
 select 'SPORTS & FITNESS' as vertical, 'vsports' as col, count(distinct clean_url) as vertical_count from static_vertical_distribution where vsports union all
 select 'TRAVEL' as vertical, 'vtravel' as col, count(distinct clean_url) as vertical_count from static_vertical_distribution where vtravel)

**Select  vertical,col,vertical_count from cte Order by vertical_count DESC LIMIT 1**
)



WITH cte AS(
 Select clean_url FROM table2017_09_11 where 
(**Select c2.col from c2 c2**) UNION ALL  Select clean_url FROM table2017_09_10 where (**Select c2.col from c2 c2**) 
UNION ALL  Select clean_url FROM table2017_09_09 where (**Select c2.col from c2 c2**))
Select clean_url,count(clean_url) as count1 from cte GROUP BY clean_url ORDER by count1 DESC LIMIT 10;
```

Comment: looks like your column is not boolean, it's varchar. is there a chance it just holds "true" or "false" text values? then the fix would be `where colname::boolean`

Comment: Mysql or redshift, which one is it?